# If the older brother was married, is Yibbum still permissible?

Tags: yibbum-chalitza-levirate

Doing a study and I’m trying to figure out the rule surrounding Yibbum, the marriage of an older brother to the widowed sister in law. I can’t find any mention of the older brothers marital status having sway one way or another. Also This study is in the traditional sense, so I’m not looking so much at the current thoughts on it, but what was customary during Roman rule?

Comment: Also, fwiw the brother in the case of yibbum can be either older or younger.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57889/759

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do we do when chalitza is impossible?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57884/what-do-we-do-when-chalitza-is-impossible)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Damion and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 4):

Yes Yibbum is permissible  when the surviving  brother is married.

The oldest brother is the one who the Torah prefers to do Yibum.  (Yevomos  24A)  His marital status doesn't seem to have been a consideration. Particularly since according to Torah law there is no issue with having more than one wife. The Mishnah and Gemara discusses  plenty of (mostly hypothetical) cases of married men doing Yibbum.

As  far as what was actually done under the Roman rule:  When discussing  a Mitzvah that hasn't widely been  in practice  for centuries it is difficult to  know for certain all the Rabbinic considerations used before practical real  life applications  . To answer the question however, it probably depended  on  how agreeable people were  in general to the concept of having multiple wives in that particular  location.

Based on a Posuk, the Gemara (Yevamos 44A) says,  that if there was (e.g.) a large age gap between  the widow  and the brother, Beis Din would try to  convince them not to do Yibbum and end up with an unhappy marriage. It's safe to assume  they would have done the same in a place where multiple wives  didn't  work  out.

Note: Although the reasons   for not doing Yibbum today and the reasons for not having more than one wife today,  are not the same, generally speaking  the communities that had a more positive  attitude towards multiple wives were also much later to  stop doing Yibbum  in favor of Chalitza.